# Prove the space curve doest not have an asymptote

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Prove that the function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2: t \mapsto \left(t, at^2 + bt +c\right)$ doesn’t have an asymptote.

Here what I thought so far:

First of all Im using this definition for a line $L$ to be an asymptote of a curve:

$$
\lim\limits_{t \to A} d(f(t),L) = 0
$$

Where $A$ can be $\pm \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{t \to A} \left|f(t)\right| = \infty$.

The first solution I came up with is more conceptual, and since I want to practice my formal proof writing, I want to prove it using a more formal (delta epsilon) fashion.

Here’s the first solution:

1. By the definition of asymptote and the continuity of $f(t)$ and since $d(f(t), L) \geq \left|f(t) - L\right|$:

By contradiction, let’s assume the function does have an asymptote L. Then

$$
\lim\limits_{t \to A} \left|f(t) - L\right| = \left| \lim\limits_{t \to A} f(t) - L\right|= 0 \implies \lim\limits_{t \to A} f(t) = z \in L
$$

Which is, the sequence in $f(t)$ converges to a point in the line. So now, since the point $z$ lies in the line, we can use the fact that their derivative vector also matches the lines direction. But using the Lagrange Integral error bound for the parabola we can check that the function and the line at $z$ at the direction of it’s derivative diverges, which is, the derivative should match $L$’s derivative through any point, as well as the function $f(t)$ should be arbitrarily close to $L$, but the integral error shows the opposite. A contradiction.

Although this first solutions seems to make sense, it seems to lack formalism since Im using a point within the line on the limit. So I though of another way:

2. Since the function $f(t)$ has a well defined and simple expression, explicitly calculate the distance between $f(t)$ and its projection onto a generic parametric line $L(s) = p + vs $. This yields a quadratic expression that clearly does not converges to zero. So it shows no generic line can indefinite approach the parabola.

My questions are: are those 2 solutions reasonable or correct?

Second question is: is there a more formal delta epsilon way to solve it (possibly also more elegant?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is a point of $L$, then by definition $$d(f(t),L) \le |f(t)−z|$$ and not the other way around, and this invalidates your first proof.

The second approach works, but of course requires some calculations. Anyway, there are some characterizations that allows for a somewhat simpler proof. For instance, with your notations, a function has an asymptote (at infinity) iff
$$ \exists \lim_{t\to\pm\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t} := m\in \mathbf{R}$$
and
$$ \exists \lim_{t\to\pm\infty} f(t)-mt := q\in \mathbf{R}.$$
In this case the line $t\mapsto mt+q$ is the asymptote.

On the contrary in your case $ \lim_{t\to\pm\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t} $ is not finite, hence there is no asymptote.

Comment: I see. This point $q$ of the parametric line is anyone that will make the function $f$ and the line to be close enough in the limit so we can use same parameter for both, right? I was stuck to the fact that I could not parametrize the line with same parameter as the function as the parameter value at which it approaches $f$ is not the same as the value for $t$ in general. But now I see it doesn’t matter because they will get close enough so for some point $p$ we can use same parameter for both so the limits you wrote will exist if the asymptote exists. Is that reasoning correct?

Comment: I mean, in general, for arbitrary parametrization of $f$, the fact that $f$ approaches L as a set of points, doesn’t imply that it approaches L as a parametrization of t. Their distance might diverge evolving t from some point p in L. But I guess if we choose p to be very close to $f$ and parametrize both by arc length, then I guess the limits you wrote will exist. Still that would need to prove right?

Comment: I apologize but don't fully follow your line of reasoning. Mine is just: every possible candidate to be an asymptote has the form $t\mapsto mt+q$. If it is indeed an asymptote then $m$ and $q$ must satisfy the given properties.

Comment: I understand the general meaning. But as for the proof what Im reasoning is: if you use the same parameter t for the line and the function, then it means their difference is a function of t, and then its not always true that this difference converges when t goes do infinity. If you have |f(t)-p-vs|, with the arbitrary line over some other parameter s, then its true that for some t and some s, this difference is arbitrarily close. Imagine if you have a parametrization of f which the projection of f(t) in p+vs varies non linearly. Then the difference f(t)-p-vt will grow.

Comment: Although the function is close to the line considering the line as a set of points.

Comment: Im speaking of a general case, not particularly of function f(t) as a parabola such as in the question.

Comment: Giafazio: sorry, can you please help with this question? Maybe I was not clear about where Im in doubt still. What Im thinking is that you used the line parametrized as same parameter as the parabola and derived the limits in your answer, so can it happen what I mention in previous reply? Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Cannot every line be always parametrized that way?

Comment: can I try to just clarify something so I can make my question clearer. How did you arrive at this limit: $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t} := m\in \mathbf{R}$
What I thought you did was: used the definition of asymptote I provided and plugged f and L as parameter of t: $ \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}|f(t) - p + vt|$ and divided by $t\neq 0$. Is that right?